# How to make foreign key reference to column in parent table of specific table

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I am using `mysql` database, by using it I created five tables `course`, `section`, `subsection`, `school` and `school_course` without any problems

```
CREATE TABLE `course` (
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE `section` (
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    courseId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`courseId`) REFERENCES `course` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `subsection` (
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    sectionId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`sectionId`) REFERENCES `section` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `school` (
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE `school_course` (
    id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    schoolId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    courseId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`schoolId`) REFERENCES `school` (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`courseId`) REFERENCES `course` (id),
    UNIQUE (`schoolId`, `courseId`)
);
```

---

The problem comes one when I created `school_course_subsection` table

```
CREATE TABLE `school_course_subsection` (
    `id` BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `schoolId` BIGINT NOT NULL,
    `courseId` BIGINT NOT NULL,
    `subsectionId` BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (`schoolId`, `courseId`) REFERENCES `school_course` (`schoolId`, `courseId`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`subsectionId`, `courseId`) REFERENCES `subsection` (`id`, `sectionId.courseId`)
                                                                             ^^^^^ ERROR
);
```

What I want to do is check if the inserted row's

- `schoolId` is belongs to `courseId`
- `subsectionId` is also belongs to `courseId`**;** in other words `subsection`'s `section`'s `courseId` must belongs to `courseId`

if the two conditions are met the row will inserted without any errors otherwise it will not

**My question is** in `school_course_subsection` table how to make

`courseId` foreign key reference to

`courseId` column which is in `section` parent table of `subsection` table

Comment: The scheme is wrong. `school_course` and `school_course_subsection` cannot exist at the same time... `courseId` and `subsectionId` cannot exist in `school_course_subsection` at the same time... it's unclear why `section` and `subsection` are 2 entities, not one... and so on. You have analysed the branch wrongly.

Comment: @Akina I'll try to improve the schema, however I'd like to know if I can make foreign key reference to column in parent table of specific table? **can I do that or no?**

Comment: You refer to INDEX. the index in a table cannot contain a field from another table in its expression. So you cannot.

Comment: @Akina ok I understood thank you very much